# Mongoid:4.x how to have array of ids as a 1-N reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have two classes

```
class Round
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic

  has_many :users

end

class User
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic


  belongs_to :round
end
```

This all works fine, but what I want to have is two methods on the Round model
good_users and bad_users, both is a relation to the User class. I want to reuse the user class, but have a distinct method access.

I understand that the classic model is using a field on user, to associate it with round, so user has a round_id field in the database. but I would be ok with a setup where. the Round class has two fields with the ids of the users as an array, stored in them.

Is this something I can achieve out of the box with mongoid?

Answer (score 1):

This will create two columns in users, for the two relations.

```
round.rb
has_many :good_users, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :good_in_round
has_many :bad_users, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :bad_in_round

user.rb
belongs_to :good_in_round, class_name: 'Round', inverse_of: :good_users
belongs_to :bad_in_round, class_name: 'Round', inverse_of: :bad_users
```

Mongoid stores the related object ids as an Array in many to many relations. So you could also use that here

```
round.rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :good_users, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :good_in_round
has_and_belongs_to_many :bad_users, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :bad_in_round
```

Comment: do I need to use both has_many and has_and_belongs_to_many in rounds.rb?

Comment: No, use only one. use has_and_belongs_to_many, if you want to save the ids as an Array.